# MEAN stack and ngResource - don't understand how to pass url resource ids

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack, ngresource

I am trying to build a little app with the mean stack and I have been struggling with this problem for days now. The app is pretty straightforward, I can create Quizes, then create questions that pertain to those quizes.

The different REST URLs are as follow:

```
/api/quizes
/api/quizes/:quizId
/api/quizes/:quizId/questions
/api/quizes/:quizId/questions/:questionId
```

I am able to list the different quizes, add, edit and delete them without a problem. However, I have an "add question" link in the "view quiz" view that will redirect me to the "add question view" and will present me with a form. When I submit this form, I get an error 404 from the server.

The Network tab in Chrome shows me that the POST goes the **/quizes/questions** URL, which of course is not correct:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/quizes/questions 404 (Not Found)
```

I notice that the URL it is trying to POST to is:

```
/api/quizes/questions
```

when it should be:

```
/api/quizes/:quizId/questions
```

I don't understand why it doesn't pickup the quizId, since when I am filling the form in the "create question view", the url is correct and contains the quizId:

```
http://localhost:3000/#!/quizes/5483e94168bff98c17e1d120/questions/create
```

A little bit of code:

My questions service (I think the problem is right there):

```
'use strict';

angular.module('questions').factory('Questions', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('api/quizes/:quizId/questions/:questionId', {
    quizId: '@_id',
    questionId: '@quizId'
  }, {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    }
  });
}]);
```

The question client controller (I just put the relevant code here):

```
'use strict';
angular.module('questions').controller('QuestionsController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Questions', 'Quizes',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $location, Authentication, Questions, Quizes) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    $scope.create = function() {
      var question = new Questions({
        value: this.value,
        type: this.type,
        answer: this.answer
      });

      question.$save(function(response) {
        $location.path('quizes/:quizId/questions/' + response._id);
      }, function(errorResponse) {
        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
      });
    };
```

The question client routes:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('questions').config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/quizes/:quizId/questions', {
      templateUrl: 'questions/views/list-questions.client.view.html'
    }).
    when('/quizes/:quizId/questions/create', {
      templateUrl: 'questions/views/create-question.client.view.html'
    }).
    when('/quizes/:quizId/questions/:questionId', {
      templateUrl: 'questions/views/view-question.client.view.html'
    }).
    when('/quizes/:quizId/questions/:questionId/edit', {
      templateUrl: 'questions/views/edit-question.client.view.html'
    });
  }
]);
```

Finally, the create question view:

```
<section data-ng-controller="QuestionsController">
<h1>New Question</h1>
  <form data-ng-submit="create()" novalidate>
    <div>
      <label for="value">Value</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="value" id="value" placeholder="Value" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="type">Type</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="type" id="type" placeholder="Type" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="answer">Answer</label>
      <div>
        <textarea data-ng-model="answer" id="answer" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Answer"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit">
    </div>
    <div data-ng-show="error">
      <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

I don't think the problem lays in the server side, but here is the questions server controller (I removed irrelevant code here):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Question = mongoose.model('Question');

var getErrorMessage = function(err) {
  if (err.errors) {
    for (var errName in err.errors) {
      if (err.errors[errName].message) return err.errors[errName].message;
    }
  } else {
    return 'Unknown server error';
  }
};

exports.create = function(req, res) {
  var question = new Question(req.body);
  question.creator = req.user;
  question.quiz = req.quiz;

  question.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(question);
    }
  });
};
```

The model on the server side:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  value: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true,
    required: 'Value cannot be blank'
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true,
    required: 'Type cannot be blank'
  },
  answer: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true,
    required: 'Answer cannot be blank'
  },
  quiz: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Quiz'
  },
  creator: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
```

And finally my questions route on the server side:

```
var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller'),
    questions = require('../../app/controllers/questions.server.controller'),
    quizes = require('../../app/controllers/quizes.server.controller');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.route('/api/quiz/:quizId/questions')
     .get(questions.list)
     .post(users.requiresLogin, questions.create);

  app.route('/api/quizes/:quizId/questions/:questionId')
     .get(questions.read)
     .put(users.requiresLogin, questions.hasAuthorization, questions.update)
     .delete(users.requiresLogin, questions.hasAuthorization, questions.delete);

  app.param('quizId', quizes.quizByID);
  app.param('questionId', questions.questionByID);

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments I believe the presented have three problems:

1. Question resource is defaulting the quizId to null, this will make your request look like: `api/quizes/questions` lets fix this by :

   ```
   return $resource('api/quizes/:quizId/questions/:questionId', {
       questionId: '@_id',
       quizId: '@quiz'
       }, {
       update: {
           method: 'PUT'
       }
   ```

Then when you save the new question pass the quizId from the $routeParams:

```
newQuestion.$save({quizId: $routeParams.quizId} , function() {
    $scope.questions.push(newQuestion)
})
```

2. The server routes is expecting a post request to `/api/quiz' and that's why you get 404 , because the server doesn't have a route for post requests to`/api/quizes/ ..`

fix this by changing this line in your server:

```
 app.route('/api/quizes/:quizId/questions') //
```

3. $location.path doesn't accept variable in the path instead do `$location.path('quizes/'+$routePrams.quizId+'/questions/' + response._id)`

Hope this helped

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Really appreciate you took time to help. I am making some progress but I still do have the same error in chrome. When submiting the form I still get a 404(Not found) error and it still hits the localhost:3000/api/quizes/question URL. The URL of the form itself is: http://localhost:3000/#!/quizes/5483[...]/questions/create . Not sure, but it might have its importance.

Comment: Additionally, I understand that the @_id should be for the resource it should be representing, but in that case, does it really matter, as I am creating a question? There should no be any _id yet.

Comment: Make sure you have a reference for the quiz resource you intend to post to then pass the reference to the $save, I see you have the quizId in the route to the form itself, you can easily read that from $routeParams and do something like `newQuestion.$save({quizId: $routeParams.quizId})`

Comment: Would that be in the server controller or the client controller? In both cases, I already have a callback function when calling $save. Do I pass the quizId first and then the callback function. Like this: question.$save({quizId: $routeParams.quizId}, function(response) {
        $location.path('quizes/:quizId/questions/' + response._id);
      }, function(errorResponse) {
        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
      });

Comment: It shouldnt really matter but I read in your code in questions resource `quizId: '@_id',` I wanted to make sure to point that this means `quizId = question._id` and when you're creating new question the `_id` is null, so you get requests like this on your server '/api/quizes/questions` because the quizId is defaulted to null when you did `$save()`

Comment: In regard to your previous comment, yes, I now understand that quizId: '@_id' means quizId = question._id. So I have change the resource as you suggested in your answer. I am now passing the quizId when calling the $save method, I still have a 404 but at least it is reaching the right URL: POST http://localhost:3000/api/quizes/5483e94168bff98c17e1d120/questions 404 (Not Found)

Comment: in the client controller, like what you did should work except that in your server routes : should be all nested under the `/api/quizes' , in order to make use of the $resource all the CRUD operations should be nested under the same root. I'll edit my answer to have server code refactored too

Comment: Also `$location.path('quizes/'+$routePrams.quizId+'/questions/' + response._id)`

Comment: I think the latest update that you have made in your original answer did not go through. My current routes for the questions on the server side are at the very bottom of my original post.

Comment: thats weird , If you change the line where you say `app.route('/api/quiz/:quizId/questions')` to `app.route('/api/quizes/:quizId/questions')`

Comment: Thanks again for helping. Your help allowed me to not only fix the issue with the add but other mistakes I had in my code.

Comment: The redirection with $location.path('quizes/'+$routeParams.quizId+'/questions/' + response._id) doesn't work, but I will find out why. It looks like the quizId is null, which is strange, because I am using it in the line of code right above it to call the $save method.

Comment: You can use: response.quiz._id to get the quizId and pass it to $location.path